# How do I calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{x\cdot i}$

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I am solving some limits in a question that is not only related to limits, and this appeared:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{xi}$$, where i is the imaginary number. I plugged this into Wolfram and it gave me $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{xi}=e^{xi[{\space 0\space to\space \pi}]}$$ and I have no clue on how to arrive at this result, or even what it means.

Edit: Ok. I get it now, that limit wasn't something I really had to take for the calculation, I just had missed something. Thank you for your answers. The final answer is, then, that this limit doesn't exist, but oscillates between 2 values, which makes sense, and that is what Wolfram was trying to convey with it's notation.

Comment: the complex exponential $ exp(ix) $ is highly oscillating there is no limit whenever $ x\to \infty $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$ e^{xi}=\cos x+i\sin x $$

as $x\to\infty$, the complex number $e^{xi}$ is confined to the unit circle. It has no limit other than being limited to the unit circle.

Answer (score 3):

If $x=2\pi k$ for $k$ an integer, then 
$$e^{xi}=1$$
while if $x=2\pi k+ \pi$ for $k$ an integer, then
$$e^{xi}=-1.$$
As $x$ goes to infinity, it hits these two sets of values infinitely many times.  So the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$; both functions are bounded and oscillate between $-1$ and $+1$; therefore $e^{ix}$ has no limit when $x$ goes to infinity.